# jquery;click function to cycle through <li><img>

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a  list of images that I would like to cycle through.  I am trying to find the CORRECT way to accomplish my task of: 1)fading in the NEXT arrow and the first image in my list of

2)after first click of NEXT arrow, second

fades in and PREVIOUS arrow fades in 3) when user clicks NEXT arrow and the LAST

is reached, the NEXT arrow will fadeOut 4)after clicking PREVIOUS arrow is clicked and FIRST

is reached, the PREVIOUS arrow will fadeOut.  My code repeats commands that don't need repeating, i'm just having trouble creating the proper looping.

My html is:

```
<div id="fullImage"></div>
                <div id="imageBlock">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="logoDiscovery" title="click to enlarge"><img src="images/logoDiscovery_T.png"/></a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="logoGoulds" title="click to enlarge"><img src="images/logoGoulds_T.png"/></a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="logoMayer" title="click to enlarge"><img src="images/logoMayer_T.png"/></a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="logoNorthwest" title="click to enlarge"><img src="images/logoNorthwest_T.png"/></a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="logoPriscilla" title="click to enlarge"><img src="images/logoPriscilla_T.png"/></a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="logoSohier" title="click to enlarge"><img src="images/logoSohier_T.png"/></a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="logoSierra" title="click to enlarge"><img src="images/logoSierra_T.png"/></a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="logoUltimate" title="click to enlarge"><img src="images/logoUltimate_T.png"/></a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="logoTaylor" title="click to enlarge"><img src="images/logoTaylor_T.png"/></a>
                </div>
                <div class="media">
                    <div class="navigation">
                        <div class="prev">
                           <img src="../images/arrowLeft.png" alt="Previous"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="next">
                           <img src="../images/arrowRight.png" alt="Next"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="gallery">
                        <li><img src="images/logoDiscovery_M.png" class="full logo" style="margin-top:0;"/></li>
                        <li><img src="images/logoGoulds_M.png" class="full logo" style="margin-top:0"/></li>
                        <li><img src="images/logoMayer_M.png" class="full logo" style="margin-top:0"/></li>
                        <li><img src="images/logoNorthwest_M.png" class="full logo" style="margin-top:0"/></li>
                        <li><img src="images/logoPriscilla_M.png" class="full logo" style="margin-top:0"/></li>
                        <li><img src="images/logoSohier_M.png" class="full logo" style="margin-top:0"/></li>
                        <li><img src="images/logoSierra_M.png" class="full logo" style="margin-top:0"/></li>
                        <li><img src="images/logoUltimate_M.png" class="full logo" style="margin-top:0"/></li>
                        <li><img src="images/logoTaylor_M.png" class="full logo" style="margin-top:0"/></li>                        
                    </ul>
                </div><!--end media-->
```

My CSS is:

```
div.navigation {
display:block;
position:absolute;
width:845px;
height:140px;
margin-left:-280px;
bottom:0;
}

div.navigation .next {
position:relative;
display:none;
float:right;
height:140px;
width:50px;
opacity: 0.35;
filter: alpha(opacity = 35);
-moz-opacity: 0.35;
zoom: 1;
cursor:pointer;
}

div.navigation .prev {
position:relative;
display:none;
float:left;
height:140px;
width:50px;
opacity: 0.35;
filter: alpha(opacity = 35);
-moz-opacity: 0.35;
zoom: 1;
cursor:pointer;
}

#fullImage {
position:relative;
display:none;
width:100%;
height:399px;
margin-top:40px;
overflow:visible;
}

div.img-wrap {
display:none;
padding: 0 0 10px;                
}

ul.gallery {
display:none;
margin:0;
}

ul.gallery img.logo,#fullImage img {
margin-left:-150px;
}
.gallery li{display:none; list-style:none;}
.gallery li:first-child {display:block;}

div.media {
position:relative;
right:0;
margin-top:40px;
width:100%;
height:0;
}
```

My JS is:

```
var speed = 500;

    $(".prev").click(function() {       
        $("#fullImage").hide();
        $(".gallery").show();       
        var now = $(this).parent().next("ul.gallery").children(":visible"),
            last = $(this).parent().next("ul.gallery").children(":last"),
            prev = now.prev();
            prev = prev.index() == -1 ? last : prev;
        now.fadeOut(speed, function() {prev.fadeIn(speed);});
    });

    $(".next").click(function() {
        $(".prev").fadeIn();
        var height = $('#fullImage').height();
        $("#fullImage").hide();
        $(".gallery").show();
        $("div.media").height(height);
        //.gallery li:first-child {display:block;}
        var now = $(this).parent().next("ul.gallery").children(':visible'),
            first = $(this).parent().next("ul.gallery").children(':first'),
            next = now.next();
            next = next.index() == -1 ? first : next;
        now.fadeOut(speed, function() {
            next.fadeIn(speed);
        });
        //var first = $(this).parent().children(':first'),
        //    next = $(this).next();
        //    next = next.index() == -1 ? first : next;
        //$(this).fadeIn(speed, function() {next.fadeIn(speed);});
    });

    //$(".gallery li").click(function() {
    //    var first = $(this).parent().children(':first'),
    //        next = $(this).next();
    //        next = next.index() == -1 ? first : next;
    //    $(this).fadeOut(speed, function() {next.fadeIn(speed);});
    //});
```

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Select a click Arena, first img has Class e.g. Active. On click get next Element After the one with the Active Class. Fade one out and new in. Remove active from selected and assign it to the new one.

Im in the Train atm and typing from my Handy. So I cant give you Exempel Code. Sry

```
<div class="container">
<img class="active" src="aaa.jpg" />
<img class="" src="bbb.jpg" />
<img class="" src="ccc.jpg" />
</div>

$(".container").on('click', function() {
    $('.active', function() {
        Var pre = $(this).fadeOut();
        Var next = $(this).next('img').fadeIn();
       pre.removeClass('active');
       next.addClass('active');
    });
```

});

Add a if do Start over from last img. 
Like: If there is no next img go to .container:first
Some like this. Took me lang to write. Difficult to write Sourcecode on Handy hahaha